# Polygon artifacts on zoom

Tags: polygon

Since several QGIS updates ago, I have been having a horribly annoying issue of polygon parts appearing where they shouldn't when I zoom in.  It doesn't seem to matter whether it is a .kmz file or a shape file. I am not a programmer type...
The correct display is on the left.  An extra line appears where there should not be one on the right.

[image: The correct display is on the left. An extra line appears where there should not be one on the right.]

Comment: Do you have some rendering acceleration enabled in Settings / Options / Acceleration?

Comment: No.  It has warnings that all kinds of horrible crashes could happen, so I wouldn't do that unless advised to by somebody that was more of an expert than me.